# How can we take random city name from the list and put them in pandas dataframe Vendor_City column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Here is the list where i want to choose random name and then put selected name in the null column "Vendor_City" in dataframe

```
Israel_Cities = ['Acre','Ashdod','Ashqelon','Bat Yam','Beersheba','Bnei Brak','Caesarea','Dimona','Dor','Elat','Kefar Sava','Lod','Meron','Nahariyya','Nazareth','Netanya']
```

[image]

Here you can see the "Vendor_City" column is blank i need help to put random values from above list and put into the DataFrame column.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: cnt = 0
ven_lst = []
for i in Data['Vendor_Country']:
    if(i == "Israel"):
        Israel_Cities = ['Acre', 'Ashdod', 'Ashqelon', 'Bat Yam', 'Beersheba', 'Bnei Brak', 'Caesarea', 'Dimona', 'Dor', 'Elat', 'Kefar Sava', 'Lod', 'Meron', 'Nahariyya', 'Nazareth', 'Netanya']
        
#         ven_city = random.choice(Israel_Cities)
        ven_lst.append(random.choice(Israel_Cities))
        
        Data['Vendor_City'] = Data['Vendor_City'].str.replace("", )
        
        cnt += 1
#         print(isl)
print(cnt)

# Here is the code of my work but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
import numpy as np
df['Vendor_City'] = np.random.choice(Israel_Cities, size=len(df))
```